# Average of the values for duplicate keys in a cell array of (key,value) in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have 2 columns in a cell array as key and value [image]

I want a single value corresponding to every key so I removed the duplicate value as: `wd=finalAlp93val;
[~,idx]=unique(strcat(wd(:,1),wd(:,2)) , 'rows')
finalAlp93val = wd(idx,:)`

But it resulted in higher variation in result. How can I average all the values with the same key in matlab. The number of rows for each key is variable here. (Here key is the first column and value is the second column and I want to achieve the avg of values for each key.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's how using a minimal example:

```
key=wd(:,1);
val=wd(:,2);
ukey=unique(key);

for n=1:numel(ukey)
    mean_value(n)=mean(val(key==ukey(n)));
end
```

so you can present them together as follows:

```
 [ukey(:) mean_value(:)]
```